# How do i pass result from waited npm script to bash script?

Tags: node.js, bash, npm

In my npm script i have the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
import { main } from './main';
import { CONFIG } from '../config';

(async () => {

    const res = await main(CONFIG);
    process.stdout.write(res.join('\n'));

    return res;

})();
```

Now want to do some stuff depending on what's been returned in bash script. Attempts to do it so won't work properly:

```
npm run update-imports &
PID=$!
UpdateResult=$(wait $PID)


if [ -z "$UpdateResult" ];
then
    echo "No imports updated, committing changes"
else
    echo "Check the following files:\n ${UpdateResult}"
    exit 1
fi
```

In short - if nothing or empty string returned - proceed with executing script, otherwise - exit script with warning.

How do i make it work?

Answer (score 1):

In bash, `wait` returns the exit value of the process. Not the standard output as you expect. You can use `process.exit(value)` to return a value.

If you want to capture and process the standard output of node program, see the answer to question: [How do I set a variable to the output of a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash)

This should do the work:

```
UpdateResult=$(npm run update-imports)

if [ -z "$UpdateResult" ];
then
    echo "No imports updated, committing changes"
else
    echo "Check the following files:\n ${UpdateResult}"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: `process.exit` accepts exit code only

Comment: @AlekseiYerokhin yes. If you want to use exit codes only. Otherwise the solution I gave should work. Did you try?